# jQuery text returns NULL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

x.html:

```
<h4> Created: <span id="link-created"></span></h4> --> Date is not printed
```

Javascript:

```
var create_date = new Date((data.created)*1000); --> data.created is epoch time
$('#link-created').text(create_date);
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Are you sure the value `data.created` is correct?

Comment: Alter the value of create_date before setting the text. See if your date function even works.

Comment: Put create_date in an alert and see if it works...

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't like you passing a non-string to .text().
Try this instead:

```
$('#link-created').text(create_date.toString());
```

Oh, and to confirm that data.created isn't the problem, you can do (as a test):

```
var create_date = new Date();
```

Comment: toString() did the trick..you are super...Thank you..5 karma points for you..:)

Answer (score 0):

It seems data.created must not be coming up with a Number...

[**js fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/39hwp/2/)

Everything else is correct otherwise.

Comment: yes data.created returns epoch time. but not sure, $('#link-created').text(create_date) does not return anything ?

Comment: Just updated it with epoch time, well the int from a couple seconds ago, still works hmm